# class vector3D member functions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to run my program and my numbers are coming out wrong. I think it has something to do with my vector3D member functions: mag(), cos_theta(), phi(),...so here is my code and this is what's asked. mag() returns vector magnitude, cos_theta() returns the cos of an angle that a vector makes with the z-axis, phi() returns projected angle in x-y plane, then **add**(), **sub**() are pretty explanatory. I just think I am not returning the right function for mag(), cos_theta(), or phi() one or more of these.

```
class Vector3D(Vector2D):
        def __int__ self, aX, aY, aZ):
                self.setX(aX)
                self.setY(aY)
                self.setZ(aZ)

        def setX(self, aX):
                self.__iX = aX

        def setY(self, aY):
                self.__iY = aY

        def setZ(self, aZ):
                self.__iZ = aZ

        def x(self):
                return self.__iX

        def y(self):
                return self.__iY

        def z(self):
                return self.__iZ


        def __add__(self, other):
                return Vector3D(self.x() + other.x(), self.y() + other.y(), self.z() + other.z())

        def __sub__(self, other):
                return Vector3D(self.x() - other.x(), self.y() - other.y(), self.z() - other.z())

        def __mul__(self, other):
                return Vector3D(self.x() * other.x(), self.y() * other.y(), self.z() * other.z())

        def __truediv__(self, other):
                return Vector3D(self.x() / other.x(), self.y() / other.y(), self.z() / other.z())

        def mag(self):
                return sqrt(self.x()**2 + self.y()**2 + self.z()**2)

        def cos_theta(self):
                return arccos(self.z())

        def phi(self):
                return arctan(self.x()/self.y())

        def print(self):
                print("The vector(x,y,z) is ", self.x(), ",", self.y(), ",", self.z(), ")
```

Comment: That's really not how you write a class in Python. And you've misspelled `__init__`.

Comment: Please post expected input , output and what output your programming is giving.

Comment: If this is intended to mathematically represent computations between vectors, what is it you are wanting to do with the `__truediv__` function? Generally there is no way you can take vector1 / vector2 = vector3.

Comment: Also, what is it your wanting to accomplish with the `setX` type functions along side the `x` type functions? There doesn't seem any reason with your code to define both of these.

Comment: __truediv__ performs the vector cross product as "A/B"

Comment: Your equation for the cross product needs to be examined then, as taking the x, y, and z components and dividing them by the other vector's x, y, and z components will not yield the cross product. [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) is some information that may help.

Comment: Lastly, you're going to need to write functions for the magnitude and the angle functions. Right now, you're relying on the Vector2D library to do these, right? Given that, your magnitude will only be the magnitude for the x and y components, ignoring the z component for the calculation. Similarly for the angle functions, they are not defined presently keeping in mind your talking about 3D space rather than 2D space, and relying on whatever the definition is from the Vector2D library.

Comment: ok thx but you think the return equation for the angle functions cos_theta and phi are good? @Jeremie

Comment: When I searched for the Vector2D documentation, I didn't find it clearly somewhere. I would also suspect that the definitions provided in that package would be for 2D vectors, and thus ignore the z-axis, making their output incorrect. It shouldn't be that hard to write one from scratch and then possibly compare the output of the two to see if they are the same though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Import this into the file:
`from math import sqrt, asin`

And here would be the code to run (with some output to help look at the answers):

```
class Vector3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Vector3D(self._x*other._x, self._y*other._y, self._z*other._z)
    def mag(self):
        return sqrt((self._x)^2 + (self._y)^2 + (self._z)^2)
    def dot(self, other):
        temp = self * other
        return temp._x + temp._y + temp._z
    def cos_theta(self):
        #vector's cos(angle) with the z-axis
        return self.dot(Vector3D(0,0,1)) / self.mag() #(0,0,1) is the z-axis unit vector
    def phi(self):
        #vector's 
        return asin( self.dot(Vector3D(0,0,1)) / self.mag() )
    def __repr__(self):
        return "({x}, {y}, {z})".format(x=self._x, y=self._y, z=self._z)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    samplevector = Vector3D(1,1,1)
    print(samplevector)
    print(samplevector.mag())
    print(samplevector*Vector3D(1,1,1))
    print(samplevector.cos_theta())
    print(samplevector.phi())
```